# AVPlayer buffering issue

Tags: ios, xcode, avplayer

I have an AVPlayer in my app which is playing video files from a stream, My problem is it freezes sometimes and i have to press the play button again to resume. For the buffering issue i have used the following code, but still no success, can anyone suggest me a solution.

in  ViewDidLoad method

```
[mPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[mPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

in observeValueForKeyPath method

```
if (!mPlayer)
{
    return;
}

else if (object == mPlayerItem && [path isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"])
{
    if (mPlayerItem.playbackBufferEmpty) {
        //Your code here
    }
}

else if (object == mPlayerItem && [path isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"])
{
    if (mPlayerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

but the above if statements will never get called. Also I am using the AVPlayerDemo class demonstrated in the here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Listings/Classes_AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewController_m.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your mistake is trying to add observers on player instead of player items

Your code should be

```
[mPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[mPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Cheers